# How to configure ajax to read my text and form the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

odd question, been struggling for two days now. Obvious beginner.

My script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table1').DataTable({
            "ajax" : {
                url: "js/array.txt",
                dataSrc: "data",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
                },
            "columnDefs" : [ {
                "data" : "ID"
            }, {
                "data" : "NAME"
            }, {
                "data" : "SURNAME"
            }, {
                "data" : "PHONE"
            }, {
                "data" : "U_TYPE_NAME",
                searchable : false
            }, {
                "data" : "MAIL"
            }, {
                "targets": [6],
                "data" : null,
                "defaultContent" : "<button>Click!</button>"
            } ]
        });
    $('#table1 tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
        alert(data[0] + "is the ID");
    });
```

And it reads the text if the text is like this of course with `dataSrc: "data"` :

```
 {
    "data": [
        [
            "Tiger Nixon",
            "System Architect",
            "Edinburgh",
            "5421",
            "2011\/04\/25",
            "$320,800"
        ],
        [
            "Garrett Winters",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "8422",
            "2011\/07\/25",
            "$170,750"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton Cox",
            "Junior Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "1562",
            "2009\/01\/12",
            "$86,000"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I get this kind of print from my servlet :

```
[{"SURNAME":"üzümcü","MAIL":"fajwf@few.com","PHONE":"6656546","ID":22,"U_TYPE_NAME":"Unregistered","NAME":"çömez"},{"SURNAME":"asdasd","MAIL":"asdasd.sadasd@asds.com","PHONE":"2000","ID":3,"U_TYPE_NAME":"Unregistered","NAME":"asdads"}]
```

The problem is even tho I make `dataSrc: "data"` into `dataSrc: ""` and `url: "js/array.txt"` into `url: "MyServletName"` it doesn't fill the table. It just gives this alert twice when I try to open the page :

```
DataTables warning: table id=table1 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

If I change `columnDefs` to `columns` , it fills the table but this time the buttons data[0] becomes unassigned so i have to use `columnDefs` .

My question is, is there any way I can make this work without changing the servlet output?

I am using :

code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js and cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules you have to consider when you are using server-side processing with **DataTables**.
On every `load` datatables executes, it sends some parameters to your server and it expects some others back to identify the **data**, **quantity** and **filters** to apply.
You need to read those on the request sent by `datatables` and apply them on you filters and data fetching on you database.

Besides the `data` array you need to make your servlet send these parameters in the response. Your JSON structure should look like this:

```
{
  "draw": *needs to be the same draw parameter sent by datatables*, 
  "recordsTotal": *total quantity of records your table has*,
  "recordsFiltered": *quantity of records filtered from your table*,
  "data": [
            *YOUR DATA (LIKE YOU ARE ALREADY SENDING)*
   ]
}
```

So, using the example data you have provided, it would be similar to this example:

Lets suppose your table has 3 records and you are loading all of them:

```
{
      "draw": 1, 
      "recordsTotal": 3,
      "recordsFiltered": 3,
      "data": [
                [
            "Tiger Nixon",
            "System Architect",
            "Edinburgh",
            "5421",
            "2011\/04\/25",
            "$320,800"
        ],
        [
            "Garrett Winters",
            "Accountant",
            "Tokyo",
            "8422",
            "2011\/07\/25",
            "$170,750"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton Cox",
            "Junior Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "1562",
            "2009\/01\/12",
            "$86,000"
        ]
       ]
    }
```

You can check how datatables sends the request in [this](https://coderexample.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/datatable_param.png) image.

You can check the detailed definition of those parameters [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).
There is a good tutorial [here](https://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/) and [here](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html) that you can check how to do that using PHP.
And, of course, there is also the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) on the `datatables` documentation.

**EDIT 1**
Try initializing your `DataTable` like this:

```
var table = $('#table1').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true, //include the serverSide configuration
            "ajax" : {
                url: "yourServletName",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json"
             },
            "columns" : [ { //instead of columnDefs, try to use columns
                    {
                         "data" : "ID"
                    }, {
                         "data" : "NAME"
                    }, {
                         "data" : "SURNAME"
                    }, {
                         "data" : "PHONE"
                    }, {
                         "data" : "U_TYPE_NAME",
                          searchable : false
                    }, {
                          "data" : "MAIL"
                    }, {
                          "targets": [6],
                          "data" : null,
                          "defaultContent" : "<button>Click!</button>"
                       }
                   }]
            });
```

Comment: Just so we are on the same page, that 3 record is in the text file and it is already working as it is. And I am using Java, not php. I will check this first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Adding "draw",  "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" didn't change anything.

Comment: How is the returned JSON from your server?

Comment: { "draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 2,
"recordsFiltered": 2,
"data": 
 [{"SURNAME":"üzümcü","MAIL":"fajwf@few.com","PHONE":"6656546","ID":22,"U_TYPE_NAME":"Unregistered","NAME":"çömez"},{"SURNAME":"Berk","MAIL":"erkan.berk@vodafone.com","PHONE":"2000","ID":3,"U_TYPE_NAME":"Unregistered","NAME":"Erkan"}]  }

Comment: "If I change columnDefs to columns , it fills the table but this time the buttons data[0] becomes unassigned so i have to use columnDefs ."

I am using table.data[0] inside the button creation. "columns" doesn't give me that option. I completely gave up on this btw. Thank you.

Comment: @AlpayAydıngüler This is odd. It actually works. Did you check your browser's console if there is any error?